# Rose's voice in Doctor Who Season 4

Tags: doctor-who

Towards the end of Season 4 of the new Doctor Who we meet Rose Tyler again. In these episodes she seems to speak with some sort of speech impediment which is never explained.

Is this intentional? Is it part of the timeline that was left out? Was something else going on outside of the filming of the show that affected her voice?

Comment: Do you perhaps have a vid clip of this example.  Watching it recently myself I didn't notice anything.

Comment: @TylerShads Back when it first aired, there was plenty of commentary of her odd speech on the internet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Billie's response to this conundrum is:

> “Maybe it was really cold and my lips were tense, because we were
>   shooting in the middle of winter and I'm always in a tiny leather
>   jacket"

Read more: [Doctor Who on denofgeek.com](http://www.denofgeek.com/tv/doctor-who/19632/doctor-who-why-rose-tyler-was-talking-funny#ixzz2cA2A2UvD)

However, [other sites](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/celebritynews/2182328/Doctor-Who-star-Billie-Piper-in-TV-mystery.html) have speculated that she may have had some dental work done which caused the lisp.

Answer (score 1):

ive read on a few webistes that she had veneers fitted to correct her natural overbite , these can cause tempoary speech problems factored in with the cold weather she reported,  causing fuddled speech !